# URL HTML parser speed so slowly in android

Tags: android, kotlin, jsoup

I need to access it via url.

I need information from og tag.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta property="og:title">
  <meta property="og:image">
  <meta property="etc...">
 </head>
```

and my code

First, parse the XML, which is a collection of URL links.

```
var url = URL(myurl)
var factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()
var parser = factory.newPullParser()

// 0.3s delay here
parser.setInput(url.openStream(), null)
```

and HTML through URL link.

```
val con: Connection = Jsoup.connect(link)
val startTimes: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()

// 0.3s delay here But I get 25 urls. sometime 1.0s delay = total 15~17s delay..
val doc = con.get().head()
```

How can I do it faster?

Comment: You could try using a newer HTTP client API, such as OkHttp. Also, you could do your network I/O and parsing in parallel across a few threads in a thread pool.

Comment: @CommonsWare //  I am currently using Jsoup. Is it faster than okhttp?

Comment: " I am currently using Jsoup" -- AFAICT, you are currently using `HttpURLConnection` via calling `openStream()` on a `URL`. JSoup is the HTML parser, not the HTTp client API.